# Migrating to new MYSQL server breaks site made with codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to migrate a MYSQL server from **W2008R2** to **W2016**. I have installed the same version of MYSQL (5.1.68), exported DB and restored it on the new server. I copied the MY.ini where applicable. I have tested connectivity and everything is working. After updating the config.php with the new DB connection I am now getting the following error when trying to load index.php.

> Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'order' in 'order clause'
>
> SELECT * FROM (`breaking_news`) ORDER BY `order` ASC
>
> Filename: C:\inetpub\https\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 328

When I went back and checked the content of the DB on W2008 MYSQL server it also didn't have a column called order on the `breaking_news` table. I am lost as to how the site was working originally using a query that could not return results, and now wondering if some MYSQL server settings could be responsible for the site working on the 2008 server and not on 2016 server. I can flip back and forth between DB server 1 and server 2 and it will work on 2008 and not work on 2016 and both DB have identical content in the breaking news table and the rest of the DB as far as I can tell.

Comment: you can create the alias of the 'order' colum and use that alias in the order by clause

Comment: I am not interested in making the SQL statement work. I want to know why in one environment the website works fine even without the data. The problem is even if I add an order column so this statement works then the next thing just breaks. For some reason in the 2008 environment when the query runs it doesnt break the website for it to not be able to sort by order. I need to find out why because it appears there are hundreds of broken queries running as part of the site.

Comment: And if you remove this order by, what is the behaviour ? If column does not exists in previous and current database, it should not be in your query.

Comment: If I remove enough of the queries that the index.php will load then hundreds of other queries on the site fail with the following error. 

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

This is why I think it is a DB setting or prereq I am missing rather than a PHP issue.

Answer (score 0):

`order` is a reserved mysql keyword https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-O

You should use backtick for your order column

```
SELECT * FROM (breaking_news) ORDER BY `order` ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the issue. order is backticked in the statement. Looks like my ticks were just converted to formatting by the SO editor.